# Creating a 2D in-memory array in Solidity

Tags: solidity, arrays, memory

I'm trying to work with 2D in-memory arrays in Solidity, in which the size is not known at compile time. I've noticed that if I define the array size as a `constant`, then I can use this syntax, which compiles and returns the expected 10x10 array:

```
uint256 constant size = 10;

function initArray() public view {
    uint256[size][size] memory arr;
    // ...
}
```

However, if I define the size using a variable, I get problems:

```
uint256 size = 10;

function initArray() public view {
    uint256[size][size] memory arr;
    // ...
}
```

Which leads to: `TypeError: Invalid array length, expected integer literal or constant expression.`

So I then try to use the `new` syntax, but I can't figure out how to use it for 2D arrays. First I try the simplest thing:

```
uint256 size = 10;

function initArray() public view {
    uint256[][] memory arr = new uint256[][](size)(size);
    // ...
}
```

This leads to an error: `TypeError: Type is not callable`, which makes sense. But then, how do I define the size of the inner arrays? I then tried:

```
uint256 size = 10;

function initArray() public view {
    uint256[][] memory arr = new uint256[][](size);
    for (uint i; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = new uint256[](size);
    }
    // ...
}
```

This compiles but creates some nonsense data structure. Can anyone provide some guidance? The fact that this is possible via constants leads me to think there's no fundamental barrier, I just can't figure out the syntax for passing size via a variable. Thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

```
uint256 size = 10;

function initArray() public pure {
    uint256[][] memory arr = new uint256[][](size);
    for (uint i; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = new uint256[](size);
    }
    // ...
}
```

The issue in above code is you are trying to access storege variable `size` in `pure` function `initArray` which is not possible.
You should understand the difference between `view` and `pure` function.
A `view` function will read the storage but will not change it and 
a `pure` function does not need access to the storage and will not change it.

I tried the following code to achieve what you expect but while executing `initArray` function I am getting VM exception.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Foo {
    uint256 n = 10;
    function initArray() public view  {
        uint[][] memory result = new uint[][](n*n);
        for (uint i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(uint j = 0; j < n; j++){
                result[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You can achieve the functionality of 2D arrays using a 1D array as following and it is working as expected

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Foo {
    uint256 n = 10;
    function initArray() public view  {
        uint[] memory result = new uint[](n*n);
        for (uint i = 0; i < n; i++){
           for(uint j = 0; j < n; j++){
                result[(i*9)+j]=1; 
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I am able to create 2D array in memory. Please refer the following code for the same :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Foo {
    uint256 n = 10;
    function initArray(uint k,uint l) public view returns(uint)  {
        uint[][] memory arr = new uint[][](n);
        for (uint i=0; i < n; i++) {
            uint[] memory temp = new uint[](n);
            for(uint j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    temp[j]=i+j; 
                }
            arr[i] = temp;
        }
        // ...
        return arr[k][l];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Mm, thanks for the point about `pure` -- I've updated the question. And interesting approach -- I suppose one *could* use a larger 1D array and abstract away the dimensions through indexing logic. I would ideally like to use a proper 2D array, though, to make the code more semantic.

Comment: @kronosapiens , I am able to create 2D array in memory. Please refer the code added

Comment: Hi @asvisosila, I tried your code but ended up with the same "nonsense" results I had earlier -- a 2D array of [[736], [3], [4], [5], [6]] values each.

Comment: @kronosapiens, can you please share the code that you have tried?

Comment: @kronosapiens I am wondering how you are able to validate that this is a "nonsense" data structure? I am able to retrieve a value stored at every index of an array which makes it "sensible" data structure 2D array.